# How to restrict Injection of Conditional beans which are not created based on @ConditionalOnProperty

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-bean

In JavaConfig I have defined Conditional Beans using `@ConditionalOnProperty` like below, so that when `couchbase.multiBucket.t1CBProvider` is defined in property file then only bean `t1CBProvider` will be created.

```
@Bean("t1CBProvider")
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "couchbase.multiBucket", name = "t1CBProvider")
public ICouchbaseDTOProvider provider() {
    return new CouchbaseDTOProvider("t1CBProvider");
}
```

now in one of the Java class `ArchiveRepo` I have Injected the class as below, so that I can use this. There are various other Bean Injections & Methods are defined in `ArchiveRepo` class,so I need it even if  `CouchbaseDTOProvider` is not created by JavaConfig.

```
public class ArchiveRepo{
.
    @Inject
    @Qualifier("t1CBProvider")
    private ICouchbaseDTOProvider t1CBProvider;
...
```

Now, if `couchbase.multiBucket.t1CBProvider` value not defined in properties file bean `CouchbaseDTOProvider` will not be created and we will get *No Such Bean Found Exception*. How can we restrict the dependency injection of `ICouchbaseDTOProvider` in such a way that, if bean is not created dependency injection on bean is also restricted or made in-effective and we dont have any issue while creating an object of 'ArchiveRepo` class.

Comment: well usually, if you do not require `t1CBProvider` you either make `@ConditionalOnProperty` where that is injected, or provide a different implementation for `t1CBProvider`. It is impossible to answer without more context

Comment: @Eugene Added some extra description in the question. I hope Question details are better now.

Comment: the question is : when `t1CBProvider` is not needed (via that `@ConditionalOnProperty`), is  `ArchiveRepo` needed?

Comment: @Eugene Yes I need `ArchiveRepo` class as it has certain other bean injection & methods to be used.

Comment: `@Autowired(required = false)`?

Comment: Just an insight. can't you create another Bean with same name which returns `ICouchbaseDTOProvider` when the particular property is not present, using `@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "couchbase.multiBucket", name = "t1CBProvider", matchIfMissing=true)` . So in that Bean, you can have something like default implementation of the methods you defined in `ICouchbaseDTOProvider` by handling the logic according to your needs when the property is not defined.

Comment: @ThilankaD Thank you for  your suggestion. But, in my project i have 10s of such bean and I can't (don't want to) provide a default implementation for each such bean. I will try  `@Autowired(required = false)` or `Optional` bean concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do @Autowired(required = false) as one suggested in the comment or define this variable with optional as you can see below:

```
public class ArchiveRepo{
.
    @Inject
    @Qualifier("t1CBProvider")
    private optional<ICouchbaseDTOProvider> t1CBProvider;
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But once I use `Optional<ICouchbaseDTOProvider> t1CBProvider` , and later in the code if i want to use  `t1CBProvider.validate()`  (where validate in method defined in the `CouchbaseDTOProvider` class , I won't be able to do it right !! I will get compilation error `Cannot resolve method 'validate' in 'Optional'`.  So I think `Optional` will not help here. Please let me know If I am missing something here.

Comment: You should check if this variable was set.
For example:
t1CBProvider.get().validate() or:
t1CBProvider.ifPresent(t1->tr.validate());